# Pycharm quotation issues

Tags: python, pycharm

So, pretty new with coding in general and im running into an issue. My assignment this week is to run a quick program that takes a name, and age and spit out a quick prompt repeating the name and stating a birth year. the big problem is PyCharm is putting everything in quotations.

So, with my input

```
user_name = raw_input('Enter your name:')

user_age = int(input('Enter your age:'))

birth_year = (2022 - user_age)

print('Hello', user_name+'!' ' ' 'You were born in', birth_year)
```

I am getting the output

```
Enter your name:Ryan

Enter your age:27   

('Hello', 'Ryan! You were born in', 1995)


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Is this just something PyCharm does? I would love to get rid of all the quotation marks, but I also don't know if im just being too picky about formatting. I appreciate any advice!

Comment: which version of python are you using, is you new to programing dont use python 2.7 as its no longer supported. Use a modern python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a combination of `,` and `+` to concatenate strings and some (seemingly) random `'`. This should work:

```
print('Hello ' + user_name + '! You were born in ' + str(birth_year))
```

The problem with your implementation is that python turns your output into a [tuple](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp) (because of the `,`) with the values you are seeing in your output.

Comment: better wrap that birth_year in a str or will get a type error when you concatenate :D

Comment: Problem solved! thanks! I was under the impression ' ' was used to add a space. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, it looks like you’re using python 2. This is generally a bad idea when you start, as python 3 is used much more. But to answer your question, you aren’t printing out one string. Instead, you are printing a string ‘Hello ‘ then a completely different string, then an integer. The best way to print multiple variables in the same string is to use the built-in f’’ command. Simply use `print(f’Hello, {user_name}! You were born in {birth_year}.’)`. However, I’m not sure if this is compatible with python 2.

Comment: f-strings are not compatible with python2 :)

Comment: Hey there! Im not completely sure what version i'm using, but it is for a class so I am stuck with what I have.